# Why JPA uses javax.persistence.NoResultException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Is not usage of `javax.persistence.NoResultException` violation of the basic principles of exception usage in Java?

Exceptions should not be used to control normal flow of program. Returning zero result from a database query seems to me pretty standard (not exceptional) situation. One which will be handled by calling code anyway.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Note that the [javadoc for NoResultException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html) states:

> Thrown by the persistence provider when Query.getSingleResult() or TypedQuery.getSingleResult()is executed on a query and there is no result to return.

By using `getSingleResult()` you indicate you *know* there's going to be *exactly* one result. Not more (see `NonUniqueResultException`), not less. So I'd argue that the absence of a result is indeed an exceptional circumstance.

If you're unsure about the amount of data that will be returned, use [getResultList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getResultList%28%29).

But you're not alone with your distate for this part of the JPA API. [This post](http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/) indicates that the only really valid use for `getSingleResult()` is returning a scalar value, pointing out that `NoResultException` is a *unchecked* exception and quoting Bloch's [Effective Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05254/), Item 40:

> Use checked exceptions for recoverable conditions and runtime exceptions for programming errors.

Unfortunately the JPA 2.0 spec (or any other for that matter) doesn't explain the reasoning behind this choice.

Comment: Perfect explanation. I did not realize I used `getSingleResult()`.

Comment: Note that I *personally* dislike this part of the API since it's so easy to get it wrong. But the intention here seems pretty clear.

Comment: @mabi `So I'd argue that the absence of a result is indeed an exceptional circumstance`. That's the original question IMHO.

Comment: @j3ny4 yep, all my ramblings about `getSingleResult` are just trying to provide context as to why this exception exists in the first place (since that's the only method that throws it, AFAIK)

Comment: IMO it's a design flaw that not finding something with getSingleResult() should be a system exception the way it is in java EE. That simply makes the exception completely useless, all it does is take away a perfectly good exception name.